# Toggle Complete and date problems in output

Tags: java, date, arraylist, toggle

I have two classes in which my program should act like a task manager. I can add items, delete items, set the priority for each item, when it is due, toggle it to complete or not complete with an "x" mark in a box "[ ]" / "[x]" and I can print all my items. I ran my program but everytime I add an item with a set due date, it turns all my dates in my items to the last due date i inputted. Also if my item has an "x" mark already, and i toggle it for it to be incomplete i should be able to unmark the "x" out of the "[x]" to "[ ]" but it doesn't do that. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my output:

```
     ----jGRASP exec: java MyList

[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
a
Enter an item to add to list: Run
Enter Date (MM/dd/YYYY): 11/27/1993
Enter priority (Low/Medium/High): high
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
p
0. [ ] Run -1- (11/27/1993)
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
a
Enter an item to add to list: Jump
Enter Date (MM/dd/YYYY): 11/28/1889
Enter priority (Low/Medium/High): medium
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
p
0. [ ] Run -1- (11/28/1889)
1. [ ] Jump -2- (11/28/1889)
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
a
Enter an item to add to list: Walk
Enter Date (MM/dd/YYYY): 11/19/1993
Enter priority (Low/Medium/High): low
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
p
0. [ ] Run -1- (11/19/1993)
1. [ ] Jump -2- (11/19/1993)
2. [ ] Walk -3- (11/19/1993)
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
a
Enter an item to add to list: Jog
Enter Date (MM/dd/YYYY): 11/23/1993
Enter priority (Low/Medium/High): medium
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
p
0. [ ] Run -1- (11/23/1993)
1. [ ] Jump -2- (11/23/1993)
2. [ ] Jog -2- (11/23/1993)
3. [ ] Walk -3- (11/23/1993)
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
t
Enter index of item to toggle complete: 0
0. [X] Run -1- (11/23/1993)
1. [ ] Jump -2- (11/23/1993)
2. [ ] Jog -2- (11/23/1993)
3. [ ] Walk -3- (11/23/1993)
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
t
Enter index of item to toggle complete: 0
0. [X] Run -1- (11/23/1993)
1. [ ] Jump -2- (11/23/1993)
2. [ ] Jog -2- (11/23/1993)
3. [ ] Walk -3- (11/23/1993)
[a]dd an item
[d]elete an item
[t]oggle complete
[p]rint all
[q]uit
q

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Here are my codes for each class:

MyList class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MyList {

   public static ArrayList<ToDoItem> toDoItems = new ArrayList<>();
   private static Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

      while(true) {
         printMenu();
         processInput();
      } 
   }

   public static void printMenu() {
      System.out.println("[a]dd an item"); 
      System.out.println("[d]elete an item");
      System.out.println("[t]oggle complete");  
      System.out.println("[p]rint all");  
      System.out.println("[q]uit"); 
   }

   private static void processInput() throws ParseException {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input = s.next();

      if(input.equals("a")) {
         addToDoItem();
      }   
      else if(input.equals("d")) {
         deleteToDoItem();
      }
      else if(input.equals("t")) {
         toggleComplete();
      }      
      else if(input.equals("p")) {
         printAll();
      }
      else if(input.equals("q")) {
         System.exit(0);
      }      
   }

   private static void addToDoItem() throws ParseException {

      System.out.print("Enter an item to add to list: ");
      String desc = k.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Enter Date (MM/dd/YYYY): ");
      String dueDate = k.nextLine();
      ToDoItem.setDueDate(dueDate);

      System.out.print("Enter priority (Low/Medium/High): ");
      String prior = k.nextLine();

      toDoItems.add(new ToDoItem(desc, prior, dueDate));
   }

   public static void printAll() {  
      Collections.sort(toDoItems, new Comparator<ToDoItem>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(ToDoItem o1, ToDoItem o2) {
            return o1.getPriority().getValue() - o2.getPriority().getValue();
         }
      });      
      for (int index = 0; index < toDoItems.size(); index++)
         System.out.println(index + ". [ ] " + toDoItems.get(index));
      }  

   public static void deleteToDoItem() {
      int index = 0;
      System.out.print("Enter index of item to delete: ");
      int delete = k.nextInt();
      toDoItems.remove(index);  
   } 

   public static void toggleComplete() {
      System.out.print("Enter index of item to toggle complete: ");
      int toggle = k.nextInt();
      for (int index = 0; index < toDoItems.size(); index++) {
         if(toggle == index) {
            System.out.println(index + ". [X] " + toDoItems.get(index));
         }
         else {
            System.out.println(index + ". [ ] " + toDoItems.get(index));
         }     
      }   
   }  
}
```

ToDoItem class:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class ToDoItem {

   private String description;
   private static Date dueDate;
   private Priority priority;

   private static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

   public ToDoItem() {
   }
   public ToDoItem(String desc) {
      description = desc;
      dueDate = null;
      priority = priority.HIGH;
   }
   public ToDoItem(String desccription, String d) throws ParseException{
      this.description = description;
      dueDate = df.parse(d);
   }
   public ToDoItem(String description, String p, String d) throws ParseException{
      this.description = description;
      this.priority = Priority.valueOf(p.toUpperCase());
      dueDate = df.parse(d);
   }   
   public String toString() {
      return description + " -"+priority.getValue()+"- (" + df.format(dueDate) + ")";
   }

   public static void setDueDate(String s) {
      try {
         dueDate = df.parse(s);
      } catch(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println(ex);
      }      
   }
   public String getDescription() {
      return description;
   }     
   public String getDueDate() {
      return df.format(dueDate);
   }   
   public Priority getPriority() {
      return priority;
   }
}
enum Priority {
      HIGH(1), MEDIUM(2), LOW(3);

      private int value;
      Priority(int value) {
         this.value = value;
      }
      public int getValue() {
         return value;
      }      
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting your due dates, remove `static` from `private static Date dueDate;`. `static` makes it so that there's only one shared instance of the object that you're creating which means when you change it once, every other time you call it will also reflect that change.

And as for un-toggling your index, after it enters the condition `toggle == index`, you're not checking to see if it's already toggled or not. So if you input `t` then type in `1` as the index to toggle/un-toggle, only that item will be toggled and rest will be empty.

Since you have a toDoItems as a class private variable, I would suggest adding `isToggled` boolean variable inside `ToDoItem` class so that you can check to see if that specific item is already toggled or not.

So in `ToDoItem` class:

```
private String description;
private Date dueDate;
private Priority priority;
private boolean isToggled;
....
public ToDoItem(String desc) {
    description = desc;
    dueDate = null;
    priority = priority.HIGH;
    isToggled = false;
}
....
public void setToggle(boolean toggled) {
    isToggled = toggled;
}
public boolean isToggled() {
    return isToggled;
}
```

And in `MyList` class:

```
public static void toggleComplete() {
    System.out.print("Enter index of item to toggle complete: ");
    int toggle = k.nextInt();

    toDoItems.get(toggle).setToggle(!toDoItems.get(toggle).isToggled()); 

    // No need for a for-loop since `ArrayList` has the `get` method to do this for you
    //for (int index = 0; index < toDoItems.size(); index++) {
    //    if(toggle == index) {
    //        System.out.println(index + ". [X] " + toDoItems.get(index));
    //    }
    //    else {
    //        System.out.println(index + ". [ ] " + toDoItems.get(index));
    //   }     
    //}   
}
```

Comment: If i take out the static then it gives me an error `ToDoItem.java:37: error: non-static variable df cannot be referenced from a static context
         dueDate = df.parse(s);
` so if i take out the static from that too then it also gives me another error `MyList.java:56: error: non-static method setDueDate(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
      ToDoItem.setDueDate(dueDate);
`

Comment: You also need to get rid of `ToDoItem.setDueDate(dueDate);` in `addToDoItem()` method.

Comment: Well now it does not give me an error but still continues to print out the same date :(

Comment: Okay it turns out you also have `dueDate` set as `static`. Get rid of that and everything should work fine. I'll update my code to reflect the changes!

Comment: Also in your `printAll` method, make sure to update it to include the X's if it's toggled and blank if it's not. I wrote it like so: `System.out.println(index + ". [" + (toDoItems.get(index).isToggled() ? "X" : " ") + "] " + toDoItems.get(index));`

Comment: one more question. When i run the program everything runs smoothly except for if I toggle the index for completed, after that I want to add another item; then it prints out `"Enter item to add"` but completely skips that part where the user has to enter a String and continues to print out the next prompt which is `"Enter the date"` @SamuelPark

Comment: So with that one, the problem comes in you calling `int toggle = k.nextInt()`. Instead of calling that, try doing `String toggleStr = k.nextLine()`, then following up with `int toggle = Integer.parseInt(toggleStr)`.